# db_datareader role along with selected table update

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have given one data base user read permission only, using `db_datareader` role.
Now, I need to give the same user permission to update only one table (PROD.CustomerRelations).

Is there any way to give this permission ?

EDIT: 
I have tried the below method, but still I cannot update. I'm accessing SQL Server DB thru Microsoft Access.

[Allow update access to only 2 tables in a database schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56587/allow-update-access-to-only-2-tables-in-a-database-schema?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I guess the above method does not work because I used `Deny` for `Delete`, `Update` and `Insert` in the screen `Database Properties -> Permissions -> Explicit permissions for [domain\user1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grant update on object::PROD.CustomerRelations to db_user

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I guess the above method does not work because I used Deny for Delete, Update and Insert in the screen Database Properties -> Permissions -> Explicit permissions for [domain\user1]

Comment: In this case you could create stored procedure that will update table for you and would be executed in context of another user with sufficient permissions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

DENY takes precedence. So if you at any level has deny,, then you cannot do the operation. (There's one exception, and that is for sysadmins for which SQL Server doesn't check DENY.) So, you cannot have that DENY in place, quite simply. You'd need to specify DENY at a more granular level (or don't specify GRANT in the first place.)